# search strings in cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple values in cell A1 which are separated  by a ';'. Some of the same values may be in cell B1. I need to search the values in cell A1 using those in cell B1. All the values that are not found then need to presented in cell C1.

Eg - Cell A1 ( Apple;Orange;Cherry) cell B1 (Apple;Orange;) cell c1 need to reflect "Cherry" as not found

I tried this code:

```
Sub Splitvalue() 
    Dim str, mystr As Variant 
    Dim tp As Integer 
    str = Split(Range("A1").Value, ";") 
    For tp = LBound(str) To UBound(str) 
        mystr = str(tp) 
    Next 
End Sub
```

Comment: what have you tried? post your code and tell us whats not working. Read about a `Split()` function as a starting point

Comment: I am not able to work in loop. I tried this code pls chek Sub Splitvalue()

    Dim str, mystr As Variant
    Dim tp As Integer
    
    
    str = Split(Range("A1").Value, ";")
    For tp = LBound(str) To UBound(str)
    
    mystr = str(tp)
        
    Next
    
  
  

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up your sheet1 like this

[image: setup sheet1]

the use this code

```
Option Explicit

Sub Splitvalue()

   Dim lastRow As Long
   lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   Dim c As Range
   Dim A As Variant, B As Variant
   Dim i As Long, j As Long
   Dim x As Boolean

   Columns(3).ClearContents

   For Each c In Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
      A = Split(c, ";")
      B = Split(c.Offset(0, 1), ";")
      For i = LBound(A) To UBound(A)
         For j = LBound(B) To UBound(B)
            If A(i) = B(j) Then
               x = True
               Exit For
            Else
               x = False
            End If
         Next j
         If Not x Then
            If IsEmpty(c.Offset(0, 2)) Then
               c.Offset(0, 2) = A(i)
            Else
               c.Offset(0, 2).Value = c.Offset(0, 2).Value & ";" & A(i)
            End If
         End If
      Next i
   Next

End Sub
```

and your results should look like this
[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

Why not just split the second cell like you split the first cell? Then see if you find each element of A1 in B1, otherwise output to C1?

This is not elegant, but will work:

```
Sub Splitvalue()
    Dim str, mystr As Variant
    Dim stri As Variant
    Dim tp As Integer
    str = Split(Range("A1").Value, ";")
    str2 = Split(Range("B1").Value, ";")
    For tp = LBound(str) To UBound(str)
        mystr = str(tp)
        'Debug.Print mystr
        Dim found As Boolean
        found = False
        For Each stri In str2
            'Debug.Print stri
            If stri = mystr Then
                found = True
            End If
        Next stri
        If found = False Then
            Debug.Print mystr
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
dim needle() as string: needle = split(Range("B1").Value, ";")
dim haystack as string: haystack = ";" & Range("A1").Value & ";"
dim i as long

for i = 0 To ubound(needle)
    haystack = replace$(haystack, ";" & needle(i) & ";", ";")
next

If len(haystack) = 1 then haystack = ";;"
Range("C1").Value = Mid$(haystack, 2, Len(haystack) - 2)
```